# Generating a jks file and then verifying it

Tags: linux, java, openssl

I have generated a keystore file from a remote server using the following command ::

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect esesslx0833.se:9443 > /tmp/test.cer

keytool -importcert -file /tmp/test.cer -keystore qpid.jks -alias "Alias1"
```

Now that I have generated this file successully, I want to test it by initiating a SSL connection to the remote node to make sure my `qpid.jks` file works.

Is there a way I can test using a standard Linux command ? Because when I use the jks file in my application, I get the ERROR ::

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501)[:1.8.0_121]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: check if all files exist (certificate and keystore)

Comment: As far as I understand this error the "[properties are set at the JVM level via system properties. Meaning you can either set them when you run the program (java -D....) Or you can set them in code by doing `System.setProperty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore)".